# How to get wifi working on 2014 MacBook Air with a newly installed Pop!_os?

Tags: debian, wifi, macintosh, broadcom, pop-os

Here is what I did so far.

1. Installed Pop!_os using a USB drive replacing the Mac OS
2. Tried installing the Wifi drivers using these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/q/55868/1162708). I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo update-pciids`
3. To know my Broadcom Wireless Card, I did `lspci -nn -d 14e4:` and that gave me

```
02:00.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries 720p FaceTime HD Camera [14e4:1570]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

4. As per the instruction, I did `sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source`  and that gave me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  bcmwl-kernel-source
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/1,544 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,068 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package bcmwl-kernel-source.
(Reading database ... 210495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.de
b ...
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-7630-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-7630-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-7630-generic is not supp
orted
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-7630-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more informati
on.
dpkg: error processing package bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 installed bcmwl-kernel-source package post-installation script subprocess retur
ned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is where I am currently stuck.

Edit: I have installed the Pop!_os 20.04 LTS version, not the current 20.10 version

Edit 2: The problem was solved by installing the current version of Pop!_os and following the same instructions. If anyone knows how that seemed to have done the job. Please explain.